How to prove an inference cannot be drawn from an irrelevant test?
Is anyone aware of good sections in statistics literature or textbooks that explain why it is essential to make sure that the tests you are running are relevant to the question you are investigating? I've read through several textbooks and papers addressing similar issues, such as Judea Pearl's Causal Inference in Statistics, however the issue I have seems so basic - it's assumed you would design your test to answer your question - that it is not explicitly addressed.
Here's an example:
Imagine you are worried that a teacher ("Teacher A") is giving preferential treatment to an average performing student ("Student X") by ranking them higher than other, better performing students. To investigate the matter, the school conducts a t-test to compare student ranks by teacher and they find that Student X is statistically significantly more likely to be ranked higher in Teacher B's class than in Teacher A's class. The school concludes that Teacher A is not giving preferential treatment to Student X.
How do I explain that this is an incorrect inference to make from this test? Is there a statistical term that captures this phenomenon?

Not exactly this, but "identity slippage" as described by Sarvet et al. (2023). You might also look into the concept of "statistical conclusion validity".

I'm not aware of a set term for this:

How do I explain that this is an incorrect inference to make from this test? Is there a statistical term that captures this phenomenon?

But the idea of theoretical models aligning with statistical models is present in a number of textbooks. Theory Construction is obviously all about theory, but spends a lot of time on how one designs mathematical/statistical models to fit theoretical models, and may have some useful information regarding your thoughts. The books Statistical Rethinking and Understanding Regression: A Conditional Distribution Approach talk a fair deal about how the data generating process necessitates certain models, which may be in step with what you are looking for. They focus on regression over tests, but the ideas are relevant to both. If you want a specific example of using a specific technique for specific data, I also provide the justification for regression in this answer with an example of fitting simpler models over overfit ones for a parabolic relationship.

I am also not aware of a general term for this and I think that an explanation that the person you are talking to would actually understand would have to be context specific.
For the example you give, I would simply point out that student A might actually be performing better. Even if the t-test was the right one (and I don't see how you get a result if you are comparing a single observation to many -- but maybe each student has multiple scores).
If you assume that A is "average" then there might be some test for this. But that assumption isn't a safe one. There are all kinds of reasons why a student might do very well in a particular class. Maybe the teacher's style suits the student. Maybe the kind studied the subject on his own.
If I wanted to show that a teacher was biased in favor (or against) a articular student, I would a) Make the teacher grade things blindly (if possible) b) Have other teachers grade the work of all the students.
(There was some interesting material on this in Thinking,Fast and Slow by Daniel Kahnemann, in which DK looks at his own biases and ways to combat them; it's not statistical though, it's methodological).
